# Triangle ABC is cut by two parallel lines. If CB : CF = 2:1 and CD=8, how much is CE?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am trying to solve this triangle: [Image of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glz3J.png)

[image: triangle]

But I don't know if my result is correct and don't know the correct way to check it.
My result is 4 using the similarity of triangles this way:

$\begin{gathered}\triangle D C B \cong \triangle E C F \\ \frac{C B}{C F} = \frac{2}{1} \\ C B=2 C F \\  \frac{C D}{C E}=\frac{C B}{C F} \\ C D=8\text { (given) } \\ C E=x \\ C F=y \\ \frac{8}{x} = \frac{2 y}{y} \\ 8 y=2 x y \\ 2 x=8 \\ x=4 \\ C E=4\end{gathered}$

[Image of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glz3J.png)

Comment: It is Correct ! Delete or ignore Point $A$ : then you can check that Point $F$ is Mid-Point & Point $E$ is also Mid-Point. Directly , we can use the **"Mid-Point theorem"** to verify your Answer !